# Set Cart Total for a defined product Category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart

I need to get the total cart price by product category, minus any products which aren't in the specific category on the cart page so just the subtotal for a specific category.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        
        if ( has_term( 'shoes', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            
            $real = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();  
            
            
            $total = floatval($real) - floatval($cart_item['total']);
        }
    }
   
    return $total;
}
```

Example: If there's a quantity of 4 products in the shoes category and each product is $50, the total would be $200 (even when there are other products from other categories) in the cart totaling more than $200.

**Update :** I am using this code to output

```
echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
```

**Update 2** As seen in the following image, the cart total is $114.99 however i only want to display $39.99 as it applies to the shoes category only.  The other product at $75 is NOT in the shoes category so i want it deducted from the cart total.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what fields you have inside `$cart_item`?